# Optimization with genetic algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

I have written a simple optimization code using genetic algorithm.I don't know why I get error during running the code.Here is my code:

```
f = @(x1,x2) 1-x1.^2+(x1-x2).^2;

A = [1 1;-1 2;2 1];
b =[2 2 3]' ;
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
Lb = [0 0]';
Ub = [];

[Xopt,Fval] = ga(f,2,A,b,Aeq,beq,Lb,Ub)
```

I don not know why matlab gives me error.I wrote this programm based on the "Genetic algorithm Documentation" bit still gives me error:

```
Error using @(x1,x2)1-x1.^2+(x1-x2).^2
Not enough input arguments.
Error in createAnonymousFcn>@(x)fcn(x,FcnArgs{:}) (line 11)
fcn_handle = @(x) fcn(x,FcnArgs{:});

Error in makeState (line 48)
            firstMemberScore = FitnessFcn(state.Population(initScoreProvided+1,:));

Error in galincon (line 18)
state = makeState(GenomeLength,FitnessFcn,Iterate,output.problemtype,options);

Error in ga (line 351)
            [x,fval,exitFlag,output,population,scores] = galincon(FitnessFcn,nvars, ...

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied fitness function evaluation. GA cannot continue
```

Comment: The [optimization] tag is used for a completely different subject here in SO. Please read tags' description before using them.

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?I just tagged optimization and matlab and they relate to this subject which is Genetic Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Objective functions of all optimization methods in MATLAB only accept 1 argument. According to [ga documents](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/ga.html):

> **fun — Objective function**
>
> Objective
> function, specified as a function handle or function name. **Write the
> objective function to accept a row vector of length `nvars`** and return a
> scalar value.
>
> When the 'UseVectorized' option is true, write fun to accept a
> pop-by-nvars matrix, where pop is the current population size. In this
> case, fun returns a vector the same length as pop containing the
> fitness function values. Ensure that fun does not assume any
> particular size for pop, since ga can pass a single member of a
> population even in a vectorized calculation.

Change you objective function and it should work:

```
f = @(x) 1-x(1).^2+(x(1)-x(2)).^2;
```

Comment: I did it and it worked but the problem is that the answers are not correct.every time I run the code,it gives me different values of optimization variables and the corresponding incorrect values of the objective function.What should I do?

Comment: @MMd.NrC that's the nature of metaheuristics in general, 1- they're stochastic and 2- they don't guarantee to find the optimum solution. Read [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/reproducing-your-results-1.html) for different answers. Increase  popsize and generations to decrease error. But if your getting completely random results always away from global optimum, ask a new question and insert your full code.

Comment: Thank You so much.I do know about the algorithm and numerical errors.But yes as You said and I also wanted to ask, I completely got random numbers.Not only do I get random numbers in multi-objective function optimization,but also I get completely incorrect and undesirable results for even a simple optimization of just a single objective function.I will put my code in next question.