# genetic algorithm in matlab using "ga" function

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

I have written a simple script which minimizes a fourth order polynomial function which is defined in my code.The problem is that when I run the code, matlab completely gives me random numbers which are far from the optimum solution.I don't know why it gives me incorrect value for minimum each time during running the could.Could anyone help me with that please?.Here is my code:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

Lb = -40;
Ub = 80;
f = @(x) x.^4-50*x.^3-1800*x.^2-800*x;

Xopt = ga(f,1);
Yopt = f(Xopt);

ezplot(f,[Lb,Ub])
hold on
plot(Xopt,Yopt,'ro')
grid on
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64918424/2093077), that's the best you can expect from metaheuristics in general, because:

1. These algorithms are stochastic in nature and find a different solution in each execution.
2. These never guarantee an optimal global solution, but they are able to find a suboptimal solution with the least amount of information on the problem at hand.

So, easy to implement for relatively complicated problems and solutions somehow close to the optimal solution. But how close you want to be to the answer depends on how much you want to spend. This is a trade-off of time versus accuracy. The following code compares the analytical solution of the problem with the answers obtained from 100 `ga` runs:

```
clc;
clear variables;
close all;

f = @(x) x.^4-50*x.^3-1800*x.^2-800*x;

% finding analytical solution
y = sym(f);
dy = diff(y);
p = sym2poly(dy);
r = roots(p);
[~, iopt] = min(f(r));
Xbest = r(iopt);

options = optimoptions(@ga, 'Display', 'off');
nTest = 100;
D = zeros(nTest, 1);
tic
for i = 1:nTest
    Xopt = ga(f,1, [], [], [], [], [], [], [], options);
    D(i) = abs(Xopt-Xbest);
end
toc
fprintf('max:%.6f, mean:%.6f, std: %.6d, min: %.6d\n', max(D), mean(D), std(D), min(D));
```

These are results on my box:

> Elapsed time is 8.251418 seconds.
> max:0.158342, mean:0.027214, std: 2.915452e-02, min: 7.094547e-04

Now another test with options that make `ga` continue to search further:

```
options = optimoptions(@ga, ...
    'FunctionTolerance', 1e-30, ...
    'MaxGenerations', 500, ...
    'MaxStallGenerations', 100, ...
    'Display', 'off');
```

The rest of the code is same as before:

> Elapsed time is 23.090438 seconds.
> max:0.093429, mean:0.015036, std: 1.727083e-02, min: 1.086790e-04

As you see, the results are getting better, but it take more to find them. Read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/ga.html#mw_4a8bfdb9-7c4c-4302-8f47-d260b7a43e26) to see how each of the settings changes how the algorithm runs. But the test itself is also one of the most common techniques for finding the best answer: run the optimization algorithm a few times and keep the best answer.

Comment: Thank You so much.I had written the similar code You have put here for differentiating of the function and so on.I know about that.What I do need is use genetic algorithm to find the optimum solutions.I tested my initial code which I have posted it in MATLAB R2016 and it gives me the correct value for optimum value.But when I run the code in my MATLAB R2013,it gives me incorrect answers.That is the problem.

Comment: @MMd.NrC I'm not giving the differentiating solution as an alternative. I put that here only to measure how `ga` results are far from analytical minimum. If I want to give an alternative that would be `fminunc`, but I know that it's the `gamultiobj` that brought you here.

Comment: @MMd.NrC But about R2013, I can't help because I don't have access to that. You'd better to edit your question and include that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fix the random seed using this (or others):
rng('default');